# Are there any opensource libraries for handwriting recognition in .net?

Tags: .net, open-source, handwriting

I have a requirement to parse a handwritten document and be able to upload the data to database, I am looking for some open source libraries that can recognize handwriting and can and give me the results back.

Comment: I'd like to see such a library in _any_ language.

Comment: You want an [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) library. That's been asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085/free-ocr-library).

Comment: I am thinking of having individual boxes for each letter and fixed positions for each section on a document, i tried designing such form and parsed it with tesseract ocr but it only recognizes machine typed characters, if i can find a way to detect characters inside each box that will do it.

Comment: @dario_ramos - OCR libraries work well with typed/printed text (and even then can be hit and miss). Handwriting is _much_ more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you look at the [InkAnalyzer by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754080.aspx). The only problem is The conversion of your handwriting to Strokes

Comment: I am looking for a way to detect handwriting from a scanned document which i don't think inkanalyzer can achieve.

Comment: It can if you can convert the document to strokes. If its a simple document it wont be too hard for you to do.

Comment: @Sandeep - Is this of any interest? http://lipitk.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @MyKuLLSKI - Honestly i am not sure how to do that, can you please give me some pointers?

Comment: @Sandeep - With alot of time and money. All you have to figure out is how to make a "Stroke" like photoshop does. If photoshop can do it anyone can

Comment: @MyKuLLSKI - Some of the stuff Photoshop can do borders on black magic.

Comment: @MikeChristensen is lipitool kit accurate for handwriting recognition ? And  ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I came across [Cell Writer](http://risujin.org/cellwriter/), when reading the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handwriting_recognition) on HWR. Looks like you have to train it to a specific writing, but maybe it'd help you.